# Not able to create Materialized query on AS400

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, materialized-views

I get an error message when trying to create materialized query in as400
I use winSql for the connection.
The syntax seems valid. 
Could you please point out what am I doing wrong?

This is the statement I am trying to execute

```
CREATE TABLE AAA.TEST_MQ AS
(
     SELECT test.*

    FROM
        AAA.TABLE_NAME test

)  REFRESH DEFERRED
```

This is the error message:

```
Error: SQL0104 - Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: IMMEDIATE <IDENTIFIER>. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98)
```

I Tried creating an immediate one as well.

Comment: if there is any more information you want me to add please ask.

Comment: What version of i5/OS are you running?

Comment: @Ian Bjorhovde The AS400 Version is V5R2M0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE AAA.TEST_MQ AS (
      SELECT test.*
      FROM
      AAA.TABLE_NAME test  )
    DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED 
    REFRESH DEFERRED 
    MAINTAINED BY USER 
    ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION 
;
```

I use JaySQL Lite and it works.